# Azure VM with alwayson AGs - expand data disk

Tags: availability-groups, azure-vm, disk-structures

I have a three nodes SQL Server Alwayson cluster on Azure VM.
I need to expand the data disk on all three nodes.

The disk is a stripe disk build during VM configuration.

Based on this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/storage-configuration?tabs=windows2016#existing-vms

I should exted the disk following instruction. But in my environment Azure prevent me doing this as the storage is part of an HA solution.

How can I expand the disk without dismounting the HA solution?

[image]

Comment: Have you read over this article?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/expand-os-disk

Comment: Yes but what if the disk is part of a storage pool?

Comment: Are you getting an error to indicate that HA is the problem preventing you from increasing space? By "AlwaysOn Cluster", are you referring to Availability Group or Failover Cluster Instance? Did you create your VMs using a SQL Server Image from the gallery?

Comment: Simply I can't. As you can see in the screenshot the botton is not present.
The disks are coming from a Vm with alwayson AG based on a sql 2019 ent from the image gallery with a storage pool disk